# Typescript Compilaton Issue With Angular Protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I have this simple Typescript class

```
export class Hello{
    myname: string = 'Scott';

    sayHello() {
        console.log(this.myname);
    }
}
```

From one of my Protractor Typescript files I do this

```
import { Hello } from './hello';
const hello = new Hello();
hello.sayHello();
```

However this results in a Typescript compilation error:

[11:48:33] E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
projects/cxone-component-showcase/e2e/src/hello.ts(3,14): error TS2339: Property 'myname' does not exist on type 'Hello'.
projects/cxone-component-showcase/e2e/src/hello.ts(6,26): error TS2339: Property 'myname' does not exist on type 'Hello'.

I can take the same exact Typescript class and use it the actual Angular app and it works just fine.  Do I need to update something in the tsconfig file for the e2e tests?  Currently for e2e the config is

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/e2e",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas this is driving me crazy.

Comment: you need to add a constructor , i think :)

Answer (score 2):

I had these two lines in my protractor config file to allow imports to be loaded from the path attribute specified in the tsconfig file:

```
require('ts-node/register');
require('tsconfig-paths/register');
```

The require('ts-node/register'); was the issue.  Once I removed it the issue went away.  Turns out I only needed require('tsconfig-paths/register'); for the paths to work.